# Hide resources in custom iOS framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, configuration-files

My company develops an iOS framework for its partner which exports some of its functions. There are some configure files which are very important and confidential (like technical confidential) so they must be hidden from the outside company. These files are used when the framework starts.

Of course, I can add the configure files in a .bundle file along with the .framework file, but people who use my company framework can read them.

Are there any solutions to add these file directly to static library (I mean the file with extension is .a) or interfere other people read it while using framework.

Comment: Hi. What are the files with tech informations? Is it a text or binary?

Comment: @Mozilla, just a text file with some configuration

Comment: I would have done so, have written the utility for converting text file to the src file. E.g.,  the text will be represent like a static array [] with chars. It will be included in `*.a` file because it's a source. Then in the framework need to add code for extracting settings from this static array. But if the files are big, it bad decision.

Comment: @Mozilla, Thanks for your suggestion, but as its disadvantage in case file are large and moreover, the configure file is a structural file so it's not a good idea to form it as source code.